# Where is a good website for python beginner lessons for my 11yr old for free

Tags: python-3.x

I was self taught many many years ago and I’ve shown my daughter the very basics on python.  Is there a free set of lessons that’s child friendly out there?
Everywhere I go seems to be free for first few lessons, I’m sure there’s some great websites out there but google keeps sending the wrong ones up in my searches.

print (“hello world”)

Comment: fyi recommendation questions are off-topic here, and often lead to opinion, debate, and spam. There's just no possible way to answer this objectively. Same with things like "child-friendly" - that's subjective. Aside from all that: this isn't a programming question.

Comment: Try [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/?ref=shm), but I agree with @DavidMakogon.

Comment: Khan Academy has an excellent introduction to programming course with ProcessingJS: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming. The entire course is free, and it's suitable for all ages, although primarily intended for young learners. I don't know whether the *specific* programming language matters to you and your daughter, but if not, I would recommend this as a great way of learning foundational programming skills. It also looks like the same site is currently working on providing lessons in Python as well: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/intro-to-python-fundamentals